# auto update timestamp in angular while submitting a form with single field

Tags: angular

When i create/edit a note the date is not adding. Is there any way to automatically update the date while submitting the form and pushing the generated timestamp to the object and saving the data like "createdOn" : "2019-07-15T01:52:33Z"; modifiedOn:"2019-07-15T01:52:33Z"?

**model.ts**

```
export class Notes {
    constructor(
        public name:string,
        public createdOn:Date,
        public modifiedOn:Date,
    ){}
}
```

**.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form [formGroup]="noteEditForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group p-3">
          <label for="name">Note Text :</label>
          <textarea  class="form-control" formControlName="name" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <button class="btn btn-success mx-2" type="submit">Save &#10003;</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel &#10005;</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.ts file**

How can i push the timestamp here in this .ts file

```
export class NoteEditComponent implements OnInit {
  public notes:Notes
  public editMode: boolean = false;
  public id: number;

  noteEditForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private noteService:NotesService, private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router, private dataService:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = +params['id']
      this.editMode = params['id'] != null
      this.initializeForm()
    })
  }

  initializeForm(){
    let noteName = '';
    if(this.editMode){
      const note = this.noteService.getNoteById(this.id)
      noteName = note.name      
      console.log(note)
    }
    this.noteEditForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(noteName)
    })
  }

  onSubmit(){
    if(this.editMode){
      this.noteService.editNote(this.id,this.noteEditForm.value)

    }else{
      this.noteService.addNewNote(this.noteEditForm.value)
    }
    this.onCancel()
  }

  onCancel(){
    this.router.navigate(['../'],{relativeTo:this.route})
  }

}
```

**.service.ts**

```
export class NotesService {

  public notesChangeInDOM = new Subject<Notes[]>();

  private notes: Notes[] = [
    new Notes(
      'This Notes is related to the thing Dummy Content',
      new Date(),
      new Date()
    ),
    new Notes(
      'The time that sun rises and sets is the most beautiful scene',
      new Date(),
      new Date()
    ),
    new Notes(
      'The documents has to be uploaded to the cliets before the deadline',
      new Date(),
      new Date()
    ),
    new Notes(
      'Meeting has to be scheduled by this week',
      new Date(),
      new Date()
    ),
  ];


  constructor() { }


  setNotes(note:Notes[]){
    this.notes = note
  }

  getAllNotes(){
     return this.notes.slice()
  }

  getNoteById(id:number){
    return this.notes[id]
  }

  addNewNote(note:Notes){
    this.notes.push(note)
    return this.notesChangeInDOM.next(this.notes.slice())
  }

  editNote(id:number, note:Notes){
    this.notes[id] = note
    return this.notesChangeInDOM.next(this.notes.slice())   
  }

  deleteNote(id:number){
    this.notes.splice(id,1)
    return this.notesChangeInDOM.next(this.notes.slice())
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your `onSubmit` function in your component class to add date to `Notes` object.

Ex:

```
  onSubmit(){
    if(this.editMode){
        this.noteService.editNote(this.id, {name: this.noteEditForm.value, modifiedOn: new Date()})
    } else {
        this.noteService.addNewNote({name: this.noteEditForm.value, createdOn: new Date()})
    }
  }
```

Note: Assuming edited note will already have createdOn date and new note should not have an modifiedOn date.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this in your service method by updating you modified date when editing.

```
this.notes[id] = {...note, modifiedOn: new Date()};
```